# Images and (longer) captions side by side

Tags: graphics, formatting

I tried to put those images side by side. I tried it with  `\begin{minipage}` but the caption was too long and trying to adjust it with /newline destroyed the formatting.

Has someone an idea?

```
\begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/RMSE.pdf}
    \caption{\textbf{RMSE:} Auswertung des RMSE 
    nach $n\_epochs$ und dessen Lernrate 
    $lr = 0,01$ für die Datensätze: 
    Amazon Review, ML100K(+Features) und ML100K. } 
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/LR.pdf}
    \caption{\textbf{Lernrate:} Auswertung der Lernrate ($0,1 / 0,01 / 0,001$) anhand des ML100K-Datensatzes. }
  \end{minipage}\hfill
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Sorry, i already changed the .6 to a .4. They fit but the captions are still crossing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `[t]`op-aligned (or anchored) `minipage` for each image; if the images are both the same size, it will line up the captions as expected:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \mbox{}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{\textbf{RMSE:} Auswertung des RMSE 
      nach $n\_\text{epochs}$ und dessen Lernrate 
      $lr = 0.01$ für die Datensätze: 
      Amazon Review, ML100K(+Features) und ML100K.}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{\textbf{Lernrate:} Auswertung der Lernrate 
      ($0.1 / 0.01 / 0.001$) anhand des ML100K-Datensatzes.}
  \end{minipage}%
  \hfill\mbox{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `subcaption` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=1.00cm, right=1.00cm, top=1.00cm, bottom=1.00cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}    
    
\begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-A}
        \caption{\textbf{RMSE:} Auswertung des RMSE 
            nach $n\_epochs$ und dessen Lernrate 
            $lr = 0,01$ für die Datensätze: 
            Amazon Review, ML100K(+Features) und ML100K. } 
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-B}
        \caption{\textbf{Lernrate:} Auswertung der Lernrate ($0,1 / 0,01 / 0,001$) anhand des ML100K-Datensatzes. }
    \end{subfigure}

\caption{Fig caption}
\end{figure}        
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank for the edit

Answer (score 3):

You could do that very simply with `floatrow`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% for move images baseline to vertical center of image
\usepackage{caption}
 \usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering%
\setlength{\columnsep}{2em}
  \begin{floatrow}[2]
    \ffigbox[1.2\FBwidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{images/RMSE.pdf}}{\caption{\textbf{RMSE:} Auswertung des RMSE
    nach $n\_epochs$ und dessen Lernrate
    $lr = 0,01$ für die Datensätze:
    Amazon Review, ML100K(+Features) und ML100K. }\label{fig-1}}
    \ffigbox[1.1\FBwidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{images/LR.pdf}}{\caption{\textbf{Lernrate:} Auswertung der Lernrate ($0,1 / 0,01 / 0,001$) anhand des ML100K-Datensatzes.}\label{fig-2}}
  \end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. I used subfloats to and an extra caption for it.

```
  \begin{figure}[!tbp]
  \centering
  \subfloat[\textbf{RMSE-Auswertung}]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{images/RMSE.pdf}\label{fig:RMSE}}
  \hfill
  \subfloat[\textbf{Lernrate-Auswertung}]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{images/LR.pdf}\label{fig:LR}}
  \caption{\textbf{(\ref{fig:RMSE})} Auswertung des RMSE nach $n\_epochs$ und dessen Lernrate $lr = 0,01$ für die Datensätze: Amazon Review, ML100K(+Features) und ML100K. \textbf{(\ref{fig:LR})} Auswertung der Lernrate ($0,1 / 0,01 / 0,001$) anhand des ML100K-Datensatzes.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```